# loading="lazy" in CSS or JS (React)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, lazy-loading

I am using react-image-gallery `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery` and I don't have access to the html of my images I need them in `loading="lazy"` Is it possible to give it in CSS like

`img {loading:lazy}`

or in JS somehow?

I tried `lazyLoad={true}` props in react-image-gallery and

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            console.log("aaa");
            imgs[i].setAttribute("loading", "lazy");
        }
    }, [])
```

with or without use Effect

they didn't help console.log is showing that I have only 21 images but I have much more so it isn't working :/

I have a really huge project so I couldn't put the code here but the important part here is he `react-image-gallery`

Comment: `lazyLoad={true}`. Why dont you do this. Library will handle automatically

Comment: Your `ImageGallery` component accepts a `lazyLoad` prop

Comment: Ah sorry, I edited, I used lazyLoad={true} but I guess it didn't work but i'm not sure how to check, in inspect element my images don't have loading="lazy" attribute :/

Comment: *i'm not sure how to check*, load the page with console open, disable the network in network tab, then scroll down. If images dont show you know lazy is working.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone why cant he just scroll down and see if requests are being made in the network tab.

Comment: @TheFool cache. (I would think he would want to check placeholder too)

Comment: without scrolling a lot of images are shown so maybe it really isn't working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `react-lazyload` It will lazy load any component that's inside it and doesn't matter is it a gallery, a whole component or anything at all
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading is a way to load images when user needs them ie. on scroll. Since, you have already received images on DOM Tree, the effect would not be working - it's implicit. You must have access to html markup to use lazyload.

I am not fully sure even if you do the useEffect on before mount it will work:

```
useEffect(() => {
}) // notice: second parameter is removed
```

Comment: The thing is that when I  do it before mounting dom it is not finding any image, and when there is already dom there are images also :/ some paradox

Comment: That's why it's incorrect as I stated in my answer.